# c++ default parameter uses other parameter

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor

instead of overloading the constructor so that 1 of them takes in an extra parameter, is there any way to adjust the default parameter such that I can access the member of the other parameter?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
template <typename T>
class ArrayList {
public:
    int size = 0;
    int capacity = 0;
    T* array;

    ArrayList(int capacity = 1) : capacity(capacity) {
        array = new T[capacity];
    }
    ArrayList(std::vector<T>& vec, int capacity = vec.size()) {
        size = (capacity = vec.size());
        array = new T[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) array[i] = vec[i];
    }
};
```

here I am trying to have the value of capacity set to the size of vector if not specified.

Comment: The example is somewhat unclear to me, especially `size = (capacity = vec.size())`: here you overwrite `capacity` anyway, so even if the rest was right, the parameter value would never be used.

Comment: `ArrayList(std::vector<T>& vec) : ArrayList(vec, vec.size()) {}`

Comment: yeh that's how my code would look if the capacity does not have default value.

Comment: but this way I am limited to having value of capacity to be vec.size() ?

Answer (score 0):

then you dont need this parameter anymore

```
int capacity = vec.size()
```

why you just dont do init the capacity in the body of the constructor?

```
ArrayList(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    capacity = vec.size()
    ...
}
```

Comment: because i don't necessarily want the value of capacity to equal vec.size()

Comment: well if that variable is depending on a condition, then use that as parameter... :)